# Handling Reusable Custom Angular Form Components

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

My team and I are new to Angular and currently have the mindset of creating a reusable library of Components to use across projects.

Is it common for teams to create Angular components for each type of input field to reuse? for example: EmailFieldComponent, PasswordFieldComponent, ect.. Or is something like this not common practice in Angular projects since I haven't been able to come across many examples of being able to attach form controls from a parent component to any form of child input field component. Especially not in a clean way.

Or is it just agreed upon for most teams to put all your form fields into one component and controlling validation from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component with input and output for the reusable component.

You have just to include the selector inside the html you want to use the component.

the procedure is explained here :
https://codehandbook.org/creating-reusable-angular-components/

Comment: I understand how input and output work with angular. I am moreso concerned with passing form validation/controls from a parent component to the custom child component which would be something like form field in this context.